# Is there a way in awk to have a "default" block that only applies if other blocks don't?

Tags: awk

I have a fairly simple awk script with just two conditional blocks.

At the moment it looks like:

```bash
BEGIN{stuff}
$1 != example{some code}
$1 == example{some other code}
END{other stuff}
```

This seems kind of redundant, so I was wondering if there is a way in awk to have a block that acts like an "else" statement and only applies when the other block doesn't.

Obviously, in this case, it's not a big deal, but it seems like it would be a real pain if you had a lot of blocks, and at the end you had to write a condition that is essentially the negation of all the other conditions combined.

Comment: you can use `next` for terminating the processing of the current record

Comment: There's several ways to do what you appear to be asking for (`next`, setting a flag, GNU awk's `switch`, etc.) but it's pretty unusual to have the situation you describe. There's usually at least a common `print` you want to execute after all of the other blocks if/when you do end up with many such blocks.

Comment: `if($1 != example) { print "not equal" } else { print "equal" }`?

Comment: I'm not sure if I have explained the problem poorly, or if I just don't understand the comments.

Comment: @Fravadona how does using next help with this issue?

Comment: With `$1 != example{some code; next} {some other code} ` the second block will only be reached if `$1` is equal to the value of `example`.

Comment: Your example suggests you have an if–else situation with two mutually exclusive blocks, but your description ('_all_ the other conditions') suggests there may be many of them. In the latter case it's important to know whether conditions are mutually exclusive or not. Overlapping conditions exclude the use of `next`...

Comment: @tripleee thanks, I get it now.  So I guess if you put next at the end of every block in a longer script, it would change the effect from being like a series of if statements to being like a long if...elif...elif... statement.

Comment: @CiaPan I understand that.  In my case the distinction isn't important because there are just two blocks.

Comment: a flag method: `e=0; p1{a1;e=1} p2{a2;e=1} p3{a3;e=1} ... !e{ae}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some approaches:

1. A [next](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Next-Statement) statement:

```
<condition 1> { <action 1>; next }
<condition 2> { <action 2>; next }
{ <the default action 3> }
```

2. A flag variable (`f` for `found`):

```
{ f=0 }
!f && <condition 1> { <action 1>; f=1 }
!f && <condition 2> { <action 2>; f=1 }
!f { <the default action 3> }
```

3. A [switch](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Switch-Statement) statement (GNU awk, not POSIX):

```
{
    switch ( <something> ) {
        case <condition 1>: { <action 1>; break }
        case <condition 2>: { <action 2>; break }
        default: { <the default action 3> }
    }
}
```

4. [if-else](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#If-Statement) statements:

```
{
    if      (<condition 1>) { <action 1> }
    else if (<condition 2>) { <action 2> }
    else { <the default action 3> }
}
```

When you have many blocks though, there's often a common `print` statement or something else you need to do at the end of them all, and using `next` would stop you from reaching that block so it's often the wrong approach and instead you'd use one of the others as they allow control flow to continue for the current input record after the mutually exclusive blocks. For example, you can do:

```
{ f=0 }
!f && <condition 1> { x="foo"; f=1 }
!f && <condition 2> { x="bar"; f=1 }
!f { x="invalid" }
{ print x }
```

but you can't do:

```
<condition 1> { x="foo"; next }
<condition 2> { x="bar"; next }
{ x="invalid" }
{ print x }
```

as the `print` in that latter case would not be hit if either of the first 2 conditions were true.